# matching multiple patterns at once in ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

Having a custom variant type as below:

```
type yolo = 
| A of string
| B of yolo
| C of yolo * yolo
| D of yolo * yolo
```

I also have a function that performs some operations on instances of `yolo` similar to this:

```
let rec swag y = 
  match y with
  | A _ -> 1
  | B _ -> 2
  | C (left,right) -> (swag left) + (swag right)
  | D (left,right) -> (swag left) + (swag right)
```

Since operations for cases `C` and `D` are exactly the same I would like to merge them, is it possible?

Comment: Note: the parentheses around `swag left` and `swag right` are extraneous as function application has higher precedence than `+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pattern like `pat1 | pat2` matches either of the two patterns:

```
let rec swag y = 
match y with
| A _ -> 1
| B _ -> 2
| C (left,right) | D (left,right) -> (swag left) + (swag right)
```

Naturally the two patterns must bind the same names (left and right in this case) with the same types.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78168955/15261315) is quite correct. You may wish to consider that if you have several constructors which encode the same information, where the name of the constructor is simply being used as a flag, you might more directly represent that relationship. E.g.

```
type flag = C | D

type yolo = 
| A of string
| B of yolo
| X of flag * yolo * yolo
```

And then:

```
let rec swag y = 
  match y with
  | A _ -> 1
  | B _ -> 2
  | X (_, left, right) -> swag left + swag right
```

You might also use the `function` keyword here.

```
let rec swag = function 
  | A _ -> 1
  | B _ -> 2
  | X (_, left, right) -> swag left + swag right
```

The pattern Jeffrey has shown also works within patterns.

E.g.

```
type flag = C | D | E

type yolo = 
| A of string
| B of yolo
| X of flag * yolo * yolo

let rec swag y = function
  | A _ -> 1
  | B _ -> 2
  | X ((C | D), left, right) -> swag left + swag right
  | X (_, left, right) -> ...
```